# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' for connect URL ' jdbc:hsqldb:db/database'

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb

hi my project is Hsql embedded with spring+hibernate

my diectory like

```
project name
..src
....domain
....dao
....service
....main
..applicationContext.xml
..db/database
```

my database name is database

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Component scan to find all Spring components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.habitz.librarymanagement" />

    <!-- Data Source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value=" jdbc:hsqldb:db/database" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory  -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <!-- The packages that contain our Hibernate model classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.habitz.librarymanagement.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!--
        <property name="cacheRegionFactory">
                <bean id="cacheRegionFactory" class="org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory" />
        </property>

        <property name="eventListeners">
                <map></map>
        </property>
        -->

    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate transaction management -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

when i run through main class it gives me 
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' for connect URL ' jdbc:hsqldb:db/database'
canot find suitable drivers...
but hsqldb.jar in claspath..!!

someone know please help..!!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the previous answer to clarify confusion.

Both driver classnames are valid.

If you look at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver it's a very simple class

```
/* Copyright (c) 2001-2011, The HSQL Development Group
package org.hsqldb;
import org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver;
public class jdbcDriver extends JDBCDriver {}
```

All it does is extend org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver and is therefore just an alias to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of XML but it seems to me the name of the driver class is wrong.
Using plain Java code, I pass "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" as the driver's classname.

Comment: I use `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` and it works, but not upon upgrading hsqldb. Might be that someone figured that this classname is just silly and changed it.